# dudas con estructura de programa java

Tags: java

He estado trabajando con un código para simular un sitio web de comercio electrónico. Como soy nuevo con java, he tratado de salvar algunos conceptos viendo información en la web. Finalmente tengo el programa. Tres clases, una para productos, otra para el carro y la clase aplicación. Todo va bien excepto porque al final el código no permite ingresar productos al carro de compras. Porqué el programa se topa en esta parte, tal ves esté mal planteada la clase principal?
Agradezco cualquier ayuda que me puedan dar.

Producto.java

```
public class Producto {
    private String categoria;
    private String categoriaMarca;
    public Producto(String categoria, String categoriaMarca) {
        this.categoria = categoria;
        this.categoriaMarca = categoriaMarca;
    }
    public String getCategoria() {
        return categoria;
    }
    public String getCategoriaMarca() {
        return categoriaMarca;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Categoria: "+this.getCategoria() + " /  Marca: " + this.getCategoriaMarca();
    }
}
```

Carro.java

```
public class Carro {
    private String ingreso;
    public Carro(String ingreso) {
        this.ingreso = ingreso; 
    }
    public String getIngreso() {
        return ingreso;
    }
    public String toString() {
        return "Este producto " + this.getIngreso() + " ha sido ingresado al carro de compras.";
    }
}
```

Aplicación.java

```
import java.util.*;
public class Aplicacion {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {
        Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Producto> catalogo = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        ArrayList<Carro> ingreso = new ArrayList<Carro>(); 
        int productos = 1;
        int contador = 0;
        String cat, catMarca;
        String resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4;
        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Escriba la categoría del producto: ");
            cat = s.next();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el producto: ");
            catMarca = s.next(); 
            catalogo.add(new Producto(cat, catMarca)); 
        }
        System.out.println("Para ver el catálogo de productos, presione 0 ");
        productos = s.nextInt();
        if (productos == 0) {
            for (int f = 0; f < catalogo.size(); f++) {
                System.out.println(catalogo.get(f));
            } 
        } 
        System.out.println("Deseas agregar alguno de estos productos al carro de compras?: ");
        resp1 = s.next();
        if (resp1 == "si" || resp1 == "SI" || resp1 == "Si") {
            System.out.println("Indica el producto que deseas ingresar");
            resp2 = s.next();
            ingreso.add(new Carro(resp2));
            System.out.println("Deseas agregar algun producto más al carro de compras?: ");
            resp3 = s.next();
            while (resp3 == "si" || resp1 == "SI" || resp1 == "Si") {
                contador = contador + 1;
                ingreso.add(new Carro(resp3));
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Deseas ver los productos ingresados al carro de compras? ");
        resp4 = s.next();
        if (resp4 == "si" || resp4 == "SI" || resp4 == "Si") {
            for (int h = 0; h < ingreso.size(); h++) {
                System.out.println(ingreso.get(h));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Vas a tener que ser más específico en cuanto al problema y el lugar donde sucede el problema. Por ahora, no está muy claro. De hecho, el título mismo refleja que no estás siendo lo suficientemente específico y claro.

Comment: [Te he votado negativamente porque solo dices que no funciona.](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2871/15855)

Comment: Te recomiendo que en la clase Carro añadas un ArrayList de Productos en lugar de hacerlo en el main. También en la clase Aplicacion puedes usar un switch y crear un menu con un while.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como dicen los demás compañeros, cuando haces una pregunta debes aclarar bien cuál es tu duda, es decir, cuál es realmente tu problema, dónde y en qué línea para ahorrar tiempo. He tenido que correr tu programa y debuggear un poco para detectar "los problemas que tiene tu código".

- No uses `next()`, usa `nextLine()`.
- El otro problema es con `.nextInt()`. Cuando ingresas un número y
  presionas "Enter", `.nextInt()` consume solamente el número y no el
  final de la línea. El final de toda línea es `\n`. Por lo tanto,
  cuando ejecutas `.nextLine()` consumes el "final de la línea" y estarás listo para leer el siguiente `String` que necesites.

**Puedes resolver este problema de las siguientes maneras:**

Agregar un `.nextLine()` extra, entre `.nextInt()` y `.nextLine()`. El `.nextLine()` extra consumirá el "final de la línea" siempre.

Ejemplo:

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"
String string1 = scanner.nextLine();
```

Otra forma es utilizar `.nextLine()` en lugar de `.nextInt()`. para leer el número. Recuerda que `.nextLine()` consume siempre "el final de la línea". Dado que `.nextLine()` retorna un `String`, tienes que convertir ese `String` a `Integer`. Cómo?, usando `Integer.parseInt(...)`.

**Ejemplo de esto:**

```
int number = Integer.parseInt(scanner.nextLine());
```

Si usas esta forma, puedes recibir una `Exception` del método `Integer.parseInt(...)` si el `String` que le pasas como argumento no puede ser convertido a `Integer`. Por ejemplo, si le pasas "HolaMundo" y tratas de convertir ese String a Integer, obviamente no se va a poder. Para manejar esas excepciones, deberás usar un bloque `try-catch`. Por esta razón, asegurate que si usas esta forma, el valor ingresado siempre sea un número. Otra ventaja de esta forma es que no tienes que preocuparte de hacer `.nextLine()` cada vez que quieras leer un `INT`.

- Otro problema en tu código es con la línea `while (resp3 == "si" ||
  resp1 == "SI" || resp1 == "Si")`. Fíjate bien lo que esta dentro de
  los `( )`, tienes `resp3` en la primera y en las demás tienes
  `resp1`. Segundo, cuando usas `while` estas haciendo que tu programa
  se quede en un `BUBLE INFINITO` y nunca termina. Por qué?, porque el
  valor de `resp3` siempre será `si, SI o Si` y por eso el `WHILE`
  nunca terminará.
- En esa misma línea del `WHILE`, no uses `if ()`, usa `.equals()`.
  Ejemplo: `resp1.equals("si")`. Nunca falla ya que es específicamente
  para variables tipo `String`.
- Otro problema es que no cierras el `Scanner` al final de tu código,
  cuando usas `Scanner`, siempre debes hacer `scan.close()`. Esto lo
  indica la documentación oficial, aunque muchas personas no lo hacen,
  pero, si los jefes lo dicen, por qué no hacerlo?, xDDD.

**Tu código arreglado:**

```
import java.util.*;
public class Aplicacion {
    public static void main(String[] arg) {

        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        ArrayList<Producto> catalogo = new ArrayList<Producto>();
        ArrayList<Carro> ingreso = new ArrayList<Carro>(); 

        int productos = 1;
        int carrito = 0;
        String categoria, producto;
        String resp1, resp2, resp3, resp4;

        for(int i=0; i<2; i++) {
            System.out.println("Escriba la categoría del producto: ");
            categoria = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("Ingrese el producto: ");
            producto = scan.nextLine(); 
            catalogo.add(new Producto(categoria, producto)); 
        }

        System.out.println("Para ver el catálogo de productos, presione 0 ");
        int opcion = Integer.parseInt(scan.nextLine());
        if (opcion == 0) {
            for (int f = 0; f < catalogo.size(); f++) {
                System.out.println(catalogo.get(f));
            } 
        } 

        System.out.println("Deseas agregar alguno de estos productos al carro de compras?: ");
        resp1 = scan.nextLine();
        System.out.println(resp1);

        if (resp1.equals("si") || resp1.equals("SI") || resp1.equals("Si")) {
            System.out.println("Indica el producto que deseas ingresar");
            resp2 = scan.nextLine();
            ingreso.add(new Carro(resp2));

            System.out.println("Deseas agregar algun producto más al carro de compras?: ");
            resp3 = scan.nextLine();
            if (resp3.equals("si") || resp3.equals("SI") || resp3.equals("Si")) {
                carrito = carrito + 1;
                ingreso.add(new Carro(resp3));
            }
        }


        scan.close(); // Debes cerrar el Scanner
    }
}
```

Espero haberte ayudado amigo.

Comment: Muchas gracias Robert Gomez. Ahora me queda más claro.

Comment: Siempre, estamos para ayudarnos mutuamente. Si te sirvió mi respuesta, no olvides elegirla como Respuesta Seleccionada. Saludos!.

Comment: Robert Gomez, cómo se elige una respuesta seleccionada?

Comment: La puse como útil. No sé si es lo mismo. Saludos.

Comment: @virtual8870 Hola amigo, para elegir una Respuesta como Elegida, abajo de los botones de votación debe aparecerte un acotejo (check), le das click y esta cambia a color verde indicando que esa respuesta ha sido la que ha solucionado tu problema.