# Problema al implementar un Scanner en una estructura Switch

Tags: java, java-util-scanner

Hola estoy teniendo un problema al implementar un Scanner dentro de una estructura Switch os dejo por aquí un ejemplo de como tengo mi código.

**Problema:**

Al ejecutar el programa me salta el case del switch, no me permite introducir los datos y el programa continúa. Mi problema a diferencia de otros es que el programa no se detiene poder introducir los datos, ejecuta el case y sigue de largo al llegar al `scanner.nextLine();`

**He intentado:**

Lo estoy haciendo con una estructura case (switch), al modificar mi código y al poner esta linea  `micurso.setNombre("Programacion");` En vez de `micurso.setNombre(scanner.nextLine());` Funciona perfectamente pero mi intención es que el usuario introduzca el nombre por teclado.

**Mi código hasta ahora:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String passwd, user,passwd2,user2;
        boolean correcto=false;
        int opcion;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        Cursos micurso=new Cursos();

        user="acoidan";
        passwd="root";

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce tu usuario y contraseña");
            System.out.print("Usuario: ");
            user2=scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Contraseña: ");
            passwd2=scanner.nextLine();

            if (user.equals(user2) && passwd.equals(passwd2)){

                System.out.println("Bienvenido al programa");
                correcto=true;

                do {

                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println("Curso:");
                    System.out.println("1. Añadir curso.");
                    System.out.println("2. Listar curso.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println("Alumnos:");
                    System.out.println("3.Añadir alumno.");
                    System.out.println("4. Listar alumnos.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println("0. Salir");

                    opcion=scanner.nextInt();

                    switch (opcion){

                        case 1:

                            System.out.println("Nombre del curso: ");
                            micurso.setNombre(scanner.nextLine());

                            break;

                        case 2:

                            System.out.println("Opcion 2");
                            System.out.println(micurso.consultaNombre());
                            break;

                        case 3:

                            System.out.println("Opcion 3");
                            break;

                        case 4:

                            System.out.println("Opcion 4");
                            break;

                        default:

                            opcion=0;
                            break;

                    }
                }while (opcion!=0);

            }else {

                System.out.println("Usuario o contraseña incorrecta");

            }
        }while (correcto==false);

    }

}
```

Y la otra clase que tengo:

```
class Cursos {

    String nombre;

    String consultaNombre(){

        return nombre;

    }

    void setNombre(String nombre){

        this.nombre=nombre;

    }

}
```

Gracias de antemano a todo al que quiera ayudar.

Comment: ¿Cual es el problema?, debes especificarlo por favor.

Comment: Perdón que soy nuevo por aqui, al ejecutarlo me salta el case, no me permite introducir los datos, y el programa continua.

Comment: Acoidan: no es necesario indicar en el título que se ha solucionado, al aceptar una respuesta estás ya diciéndolo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema es algo común a la hora de usar `Scanner` con `String` e `Int`. He respondido a este problema muchas veces, una búsqueda rápida por el sitio web te habría ayudado. La solución a tu problema lo he explicado en detalle en este enlace, te recomiendo que entres al siguiente enlace y leas detenidamente mi respuesta: [dudas con estructura de programa java](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/117288/dudas-con-estructura-de-programa-java/117317#117317). Estoy seguro que te va a servir!.

Para solucionar tu problema rápidamente, comienzo por decirte unas cuantas cosas sobre tu código, problemas y sugerencias.

**1. Solución a tu problema con Scanner al utilizar String e Int:**

El problema es con `.nextInt()`. Cuando ingresas un número y presionas "Enter", `.nextInt()` consume solamente el número y no el final de la línea. El final de toda línea es `\n`. Por lo tanto, cuando ejecutas `.nextLine()` después de un `.nextInt()` consumes el "final de la línea" y no lo que el usuario ha ingresado por teclado.

Para solucionar esto debes agregar un `.nextLine()` extra, entre `.nextInt()` y `.nextLine()`. El `.nextLine()` extra consumirá el "final de la línea" siempre.

**Ejemplo:**

```
int number = scanner.nextInt();
scanner.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"
String string1 = scanner.nextLine();
```

**Tu código arreglado:**

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Ejercicio {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String passwd, user,passwd2,user2;
        boolean correcto=false;
        int opcion;
        Scanner scanner=new Scanner(System.in);
        Cursos micurso=new Cursos();

        user="acoidan";
        passwd="root";

        do {
            System.out.println("Introduce tu usuario y contraseña");
            System.out.print("Usuario: ");
            user2=scanner.nextLine();
            System.out.print("Contraseña: ");
            passwd2=scanner.nextLine();

            if (user.equals(user2) && passwd.equals(passwd2)){

                System.out.println("Bienvenido al programa");
                correcto=true;

                do {

                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println("Curso:");
                    System.out.println("1. Añadir curso.");
                    System.out.println("2. Listar curso.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println("Alumnos:");
                    System.out.println("3.Añadir alumno.");
                    System.out.println("4. Listar alumnos.");
                    System.out.println("-----------------------");
                    System.out.println("0. Salir");

                    opcion=scanner.nextInt();

                    switch (opcion){

                        case 1:

                            System.out.println("Nombre del curso: ");
                            scanner.nextLine(); // Consume "\n"
                            micurso.setNombre(scanner.nextLine());

                            break;

                        case 2:

                            System.out.println("Opcion 2");
                            System.out.println(micurso.getNombre());
                            break;

                        case 3:

                            System.out.println("Opcion 3");
                            break;

                        case 4:

                            System.out.println("Opcion 4");
                            break;

                        default:

                            opcion=0;
                            break;

                    }
                }while (opcion!=0);

            }else {

                System.out.println("Usuario o contraseña incorrecta");

            }
        }while (correcto==false);

        // Cerrar Scanner
        scanner.close();
    }
}
```

**2. Debes cerrar el Scanner**

Otro problema es que no cierras el `Scanner` al final de tu código, cuando usas `Scanner`, siempre debes hacer `scanner.close()`. Esto lo indica la documentación oficial, aunque muchas personas no lo hacen, pero si los jefes lo dicen, por qué no hacerlo?, xDDD. Puedes leer más sobre esto en la documentación oficial [en este enlace](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html).

**Nota:** ya he cerrado el `Scanner` en el código anterior, puedes dirigirte al final del código y ver que he comentado la línea. :)

**3. Por qué usas consultaNombre() en lugar de un Getter?**

Los Getters, por si no lo sabías, nos sirven para obtener (recuperar o acceder) el valor ya asignado a un atributo. Si deseas obtener el nombre de tu curso, solo debes hacer `micurso.getNombre()`.

**Cómo crear el Getter en tu clase Cursos:**

```
// Getter
public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
}
```

**4. En tu clase Cursos debes tener un Constructor vacío**

Un Constructor vacío evita el error "The constructor Cursos() is undefined" cuando se instancia esta clase en alguna otra clase.

**Cómo se crea el Constructor vacío:**

```
// Constructor vacío
public Cursos() {
        super();
    }
```

**5. En tu clase Cursos te falta los Modificadores de Acceso**

Para controlar el acceso a nuestros atributos y métodos se utilizan los modificadores de acceso que no son más que palabras reservadas del lenguaje que se encargarán de controlar desde dónde serán accesibles los miembros de una clase, estos modificadores son: `private`, `protected`, `public`

Estos modificadores de acceso se colocan justo delante del tipo de un atributo.

**Ejemplo con tu código en tu clase Cursos:**

```
// Declaración de variables
    private String nombre;
```

Definiendo los **atributos** `private`, nadie podrá modificarlos sin nuestro consentimiento, el **constructor** es `public` para permitir instancias de la clase desde fuera del archivo `Cursos.java`, y los métodos `get` serán también `public`, para permitir a cualquiera consultar el valor de nuestros atributos.

Con los **modificadores de acceso**, evitamos que nuestros programas tengan un uso no deseado, como modificar atributos introduciendo valores inválidos o llamando a métodos que pueden tener efectos no deseados.

Como regla general (buena práctica), se aconseja declarar **todos los atributos como private**, y cuando necesitemos consultar su valor o modificarlo, utilicemos los métodos **get** y **set**.

**Tu clase Cursos arreglada:**

```
public class Cursos {

    // Declaración de variables
    private String nombre;

    // Constructor
    public Cursos(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    /*
     * Constructor vacío
     * Evita el error "The constructor Cursos() is undefined"
     * cuando se instancia esta clase en alguna otra clase
     */
    public Cursos() {
        super();
    }

    // Getters
    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    // Setters
    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }
}
```

Hasta ahora es todo, espero haberte ayudado y despejado todas tus dudas y a que de aquí en adelante tengas más experiencia para que también puedas ayudar a otros compañeros en el sitio web. Saludos amigo!.

Comment: Me has ayudado muchísimo compañero, lo que según me han explicado los atributos por defecto si no les pones nada están en private( no se si me explicaron mal ) pero asi me lo enseñaron, alomejor estoy equivocado. Y el getter lo tenia solo que con el nombre consulta aunque bueno ya lo cambie ya que como dices es mas correcto de esa forma. Pero igualmente muchas gracias compañero no me habia percatado de este error.

Comment: @AcoidanNegrínSocorro Hola, estás incorrecto. Java nos da la opción de no usar un modificador de acceso y al no hacerlo, el atributo tendrá un acceso conocido como `default` (acceso por defecto) que permite que tanto la propia clase como las clases del mismo paquete accedan a dichos atributos. Lo mas normal es que los atributos sean `private` para que no sean modificados directamente desde fuera, ademas se suelen usar los métodos `get` y `set` para modificar y mostrar el valor de atributos.

Comment: Vale muchas gracias entonces la explicacion que me dieron estaba mal de hay mi error.

Comment: @AcoidanNegrínSocorro Tenías unos cuantos problemas. Tu error no era específicamente por el modificador de acceso. En el futuro con más experiencia encontrarás situaciones donde necesites usar atributos `default`, pero por ahora no será necesario, siempre utiliza modificadores de acceso en tus atributos. Otra cosa, recuerda también votar la Respuesta, de esa forma mi Respuesta estará en primera posición para que otros compañeros con el mismo problema puedan ver la solución rápidamente. Cualquier otra duda que tengas, estamos para ayudarnos.

Comment: No me permite votarla por que tengo menos de 15 puntos de reputación, pero desde que llegue a los 15 puntos entrare y votare la respuesta. Muchas gracias